# Projeto WebAPI - .NET

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Asp.Net WebApi (primeira aplicação REST).

Até o momento esta tudo ok, mesmo por que estou na fase de testes utilizando o PostMan. Acredito que devo finalizar esta primeira etapa dentro de duas semanas.

O projeto possui as camadas de Serviço, Domínio, Infra, WebApi, Validações e Injeção de Dependência, todas separadas por projetos dentro da mesma solução.

O próximo passo será desenvolver a "Camada" que servirá como View aos usuários.

*Deverei utilizar AngularJs2*.

Agora vem a minha duvida.

Para esta camada devo criar um novo projeto? se sim, qual tipo sendo que as Views são paginas HTML?

Todo o projeto será hospedado no mesmo servidor. Espero ter sido claro com a minha duvida :)
Flávio Oliveira

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Para esta camada devo criar um novo projeto?

Não necessariamente. Por exemplo, em um projeto similar eu tenho uma estrutura onde armazeno minhas classes ORM em um folder chamado `model`, meus endpoints API em `controllers` e o conteúdo *Angular* em `frontend`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A decisão de se criar um projeto à parte pode ser simplesmente de natureza organizacional.

Comment: OnoSendai, no seu exemplo você esta incluindo estas pastas dentro projeto WebEPI?

Comment: @urlflavio Sim, este é o caso.

Comment: Ok OnoSendai, vou seguir este exemplo. Vlw pela força!